# The library org.apache.Cassandra.thrift.clock cannot be found

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-jdbc

I've searched for the jar files in maven and couple of other websites but I couldn't find the jar file nor the maven dependency. Please help me out.

Comment: what are you trying to do? its generated from ant and in cassandra's jar

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I'm trying to import the class org.apache.Cassandra.thrift.Clock. But it's saying that it couldn't be resolved. So I have to download the dependencies/jar files which I'm unable to find. Can you send me link of the jar library?

Comment: `org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Clock` (C is lowercase).  Where are you seeing this from? Looks like thats been deleted like 5 years ago. Whatever your doing its the wrong direction, avoid Thrift (deprecated) and dont access the Cassandra code directly, go through a [CQL driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver)